# How to open new instance of applications from spotlight every time on Mac m1 (Big Sur & above)

Tags: macos, mac, applications, spotlight

Instead of directing to the application, how to make spotlight open a new instance/window of the application.

Tried flashlight solution but it won't work for recent Mac OS Versions.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think the Spotlight interface is programmable or customizable is any meaningful way, so you can't change it's behaviour.

If you want to open a new window of an already open app, right-click on the app's icon in the Dock, or just switch to it with <kbd>Command</kbd> <kbd>Tab</kbd> and then do <kbd>Command</kbd> <kbd>N</kbd>. That's probably as quick as typing a name in Spotlight.

You may be able to set an app to create a new document when it launches: but that's likely a preference of the application, which it will either have, or not, depending on whether the devs thought about it.

If you want multiple *instances* of an application (i.e. more than one running process), then that is possible from the Terminal by using `open -n -a ApplicationName` (see `man open` for more), though reasons for doing so are few.